# How to implement RSA 4096 encryption in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key

I'm working on a project and we are trying to integrate a payment provider with this app . The payment provider requires us to implement RSA 4096 encryption . Our project is in PHP Laravel . My question is can somebody tell me how is RSA 4096 encryption done in Laravel ? Or if you could provide me with some reading resources which can help me . Its my first time working with encryption .

Edit :  I have generated the public and private keys . Now need to know if there is a function in laravel which can encrypt and decry-pt data with the help of these keys .

Comment: What do you mean "requires us to implement"? RSA 4096 is typically used in SSL certificates.

Comment: Like we need to generate RSA4096 public private keys
then for api we will encrypt data using public key … and when we get response we will be decrypt using private key . We need to implement this .

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a tutorial and Stack Overflow is not the right place for that. It is an extensive topic so your question can be interpreted as either [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (to answer) or [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (to recommend a resource).

Comment: Actually not looking for a tutorial . I have generated the public and private keys . Now need to know if there is a function in laravel which can encrypt and decry-pt data with the help of these keys

Comment: php has built-in functions for asymmetric encryption/decryption ([you can look here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php)). But to me this sounds like you should rather use https/tls than this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

For laravel use below composer package.

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib
```

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA as Crypt_RSA;

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($publickey);
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(2);
$data = 'Your String';
$output = $rsa->encrypt($data);
echo base64_encode($output);
```

You can generate a public and private key using `$rsa->createKey()`

```
  $rsa = new RSA();
  $keys = $rsa->createKey(4096);
  $publicKey = $keys['publickey'];
  $privateKey = $keys['privatekey'];
```

Comment: I ran the following code(separately not in laravel) to create the keys . The code runs successfully but where are the keys being placed ?                                                            
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
 
//$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1);
//$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);

//define('CRYPT_RSA_EXPONENT', 65537);
//define('CRYPT_RSA_SMALLEST_PRIME', 64); // makes it so multi-prime RSA is used
extract($rsa->createKey()); // == $rsa->createKey(1024) where 1024 is the key size
?>

Comment: What keys you're talking about? if you don't have a public/private key you can use ```$rsa->createKey();``` to generate one.

Comment: Package installed successfully. but when i want to access the class using this command
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA as Crypt_RSA;
It is showing class not found. Can anyone guide me what i am doing the wrong.